# How can I use data from background script in popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I use data from background.js in popup?
What ways are exist to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Message API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to communicate between background, popup, content-script and ui-pages.

It is also possible through the localStorage.